# 日本人じゃないですけど、回答することができると思います。いいですか？

Tags: 討議

はじめまして。日本もスタックオーバーフローも興味があるので日本語のサイトも読みます。日本語の質問を読めます。よく答えも分かりますけど、プログラマーの日本語が苦手ですから、回答してもいいか聞きたいです。よろしくおねがいします。

例えば：[画像読み込み時に Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture というエラー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/14550/10899)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

回答していいと思います。

あなたの投稿は他のユーザーが意味を理解できる日本語になっています。役に立つ回答であれば、他のユーザーがもっと読みやすい日本語に直してくれるでしょう。

Answer (score 10):

私も日本人ではないのですが、出来る限り日本語で回答を書いてja.stackoverflow.comに参加したいと思っています。もちろん、英語圏のstackoverflowがあるんですが、日本語の勉強に役に立つからよくja.stackoverflow.comを読みます。それでも、質問の答えが分かれば中級な日本語でもお答えしたいので、我々のような者は文頭にネーティブではない旨を一言添えれば皆様にご理解頂けるのではないでしょうか。共に参加しましょう!

Answer (score 7):

私は英語圏の人間ではないですが、stackoverflow.com の方を利用しています。

I have participated in the stackoverflow.com though I'm not a native English speaker.

自分の書くことのできる英語で回答を書いています。

I write answers in English to the extent possible for me.

是非、あなたの書くことのできる日本語で回答を書いて ja.stackoverflow.com に参加してください。

Please don't hesitate, and answer and write in Japanese as you can and take part in ja.stackoverflow.com. You should be welcomed.

Answer (score 3):

日本語の質問に対して、英語で回答してもいいんじゃないでしょうか？
回答がつかないより、英語の回答がつく方が質問者も助かると思います。
また、プログラマーなら英語を読める可能性が一般的な日本人より高い気がしますし、
英語の勉強にもなって一石二鳥です。

Answer (score 3):

日本語で回答してもいいんではないですか。
Stack Overflowは英語になってます。英語あんまり出来ない人も参加してるが、他のユーザーが英語を添削してくれたら信用度も上がられます。
スタックオーバーフローは同じように日本語になってますでしょうか。

お互いに頑張りましょう。