# StackOverflow ¿beta?

Tags: 討議

私の注意を引いたのは、このサイトには**beta**バナーがあり、[meta StackExchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331708/congratulations-to-our-29-oldest-beta-sites-theyre-now-no-longer-beta)サイトの投稿によると、毎日10回の投稿に達するか、7-8歳のサイトは*beta*バナーを削除し、スパムである投稿を明らかにカウントしないことです。

私はスペインのサイトから来て、英語のコミュニティのように発展した投票文化がないことを見てきました。自己回答の質問は知識を提供するために非常に良いですし、「コミュニティのwiki」の投稿を忘れないようにしましょう。スタックオーバーフローは、信頼性の高いQ&Aサイトです、 そうしましょう!サイトを改善し、**beta**バナーを削除してみましょう

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Betaラベルが[2021年12月に](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3653/14055)無事削除されました。

[Christian さん](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/47532/christian)の第一言語はスペイン語かと推測いたしましたが、ここスタック・オーバーフローにご投稿くださりありがとうございます。投稿するには少し勇気が必要だったのではないかと思います。日本語を第二言語（や第三言語）として話される方もスタック・オーバーフローでは投稿が推奨されています。

参照：[日本人じゃないですけど、回答することができると思います。いいですか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1959/14055)

正式版となった[スタック・オーバーフロー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/)でも自己回答を投稿し、引き続き信頼性の高さを保てるようにコミュニティモデレーションをよろしくお願いいたします。そしてここメタでは多種多様なご意見を心よりお待ちしております。