# 祝スタック・オーバーフロー公開7周年をむかえ正式版へ

Tags: 討議, 交流会

コミュニティのみなさんに大切なお知らせがあります。このたびスタック・オーバーフローはベータ版を晴れて卒業し、本日2021年12月16日より正式版として提供されることになりました。この卒業をみなさんにお伝えできることを本当に嬉しく思います。
 
今から7年前、スタック・オーバーフローはパブリックベータ版として公開されました。コミュニティがこのように成長し、質の高い有益なライブラリの作成を続けることができたのはなぜか。それはオンラインの向こう側で毎日コツコツと何らかのアクションをとってくださったプログラマーのみなさんの存在があったからです。今回の卒業はひとえにみなさんの日々の活動のおかげです。
 
2018年に[マニフェスト](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/manifesto)が作成され、「検索エンジンにキーワードを入力することで、日本語で詳細に書かれた回答へのリンクが検索結果に表示される環境を整えること」を目標にかかげ今日までやってきました。質問や回答を投稿された方、それを編集くださり、中には積極的にレビューされた方もおられると思います。投票やコメント、タグの付け替えといった全ての日々の小さなアクションが今回の前進につながっています。コミュニティのイベントを企画実行くださったファシリテーターさん、そして必要な時にしっかりとご対応くださる心強いモデレーションチーム（初代〜現在）もこの卒業には欠かせない存在です。
 
時にコミュニケーションがミスマッチだったり、中には悲しい思いをされた方もおられるのかもしれません。しかし、今日このアナウンスを読んでいるプログラマーのみなさんに少しでも幸せな気持ちを感じてもらえていたらこれ以上嬉しいことはありません。この7年のナレッジベースの改善活動によってどれだけの知識を効率化できたでしょうか。これからも続けてゆきましょう！

[image]
 
今回の卒業と新たな門出をお祝いするために、コミュニティ主導のイベントを開催したいと思います。イベントのプラニングを行える方を募集しますので、お手伝い可能な方はお声がけください。7年間、知識の積み重ねをどうもありがとうございました。これからもスタック・オーバーフローをよろしくお願いいたします！

Comment: 　遂に！　／　簡単な LT イベントの開催は面白そうだなあと思っているのですが、一人でオーガナイズするのには不安があるので、どなたかと協力できないかなあと思っています。

Comment: おめでとうございます～！

Comment: 関連: [Congratulations to the 59 sites that just left Beta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/374096/341401)

Answer (score 7):

正式版への移行に伴い、(ロゴからベータが外れた以外に) ユーザーに影響のある変更点があれば教えてください。

例えば、[権限](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) の開放に必要な信用度がベータ版では一部緩和されていた気がします。

Comment: 変更点は正式版としてのモデレーター選挙が行われることです。最短でも選挙の時期は2022年の春になります。今すぐに権限開放への信用度のしきい値が変わることはなく、それについての精査も来年に入ってから行われます。また、今回ついに日本語版がベータを抜けたからといって他言語版と全て同じしきい値を持つことになるわけではなく、日本語版に適した値を2022年2月以降に現在のモデレーションチームのみなさんと話し合いながら設定してゆく形がベストではないかと思われます。

Answer (score 2):

[Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) で年ごとの投稿数をまとめてみました。([使用したクエリ](https://data.stackexchange.com/ja/query/1531719/questions-and-answers-count-over-the-last-year))

※ ベータ版として公開された 12/16 を開始日として集計

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]