# ベータ卒業記念イベントを企画しよう【LT会場のご意見募集中】

Tags: 討議, サポート, 交流会

[祝スタック・オーバーフロー公開7周年をむかえ正式版へ](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3653/9820)にて告知がありました通り、スタック・オーバーフローはベータ版を卒業し、正式版になりました。
ユーザが集まってお祝いするイベントを開いて、この素敵な節目に花を添えましょう

前段の告知でイベント企画制作メンバー(以下、コアメンバー)を募集しており、今のところ私と @nekketsuuu さんが参加しています。
SOスタッフの @aki さんと連携をとりながら活動を始めたところです。
皆さまと一緒にイベント企画を盛り上げていきたいので、ぜひお力を貸してください！

まだイベント内容も日程も決まっていない段階ですが、まっさらな白紙ではコアメンバー参加も、提案や意見もやりにくいと思います。
そこで下記の方針を仮提案します。

- **日時**：4月後半あたり
- **場所**：オンライン不定(動画配信かWeb会議)
- **形式**：LT大会(投稿方法未定、発表方法未定)

このメタ投稿の主目的はコアメンバー募集です。
オンラインLT大会でメンバーが担当できる作業を思いつきで列挙します。

> アイディア出し、意見交換、スケジュール調整、メタ告知、LT募集、動画編集？、本家スタッフのメッセージ翻訳？、司会進行 etc.etc...

幅広い活動となりますのでスキルに関わらず有志のご参加をお待ちしております。
ご興味のある方は、この投稿のコメントや回答、[SOja交流会部屋チャットルーム](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95328/soja)にて書き込みをお願いします。

この投稿の副目的は「ベータ卒業記念イベントをやりましょう」という意志表示と、企画へのご意見募集です。
前者は、日時や内容が全部決まってから「やります！」と言うよりも企画段階の構想をオープンにする方が手作り感と親しみが出る気がするので。
後者は、どなたからも企画のご意見ご提案を随時歓迎いたします。こちらも回答やチャットでお寄せください。

---

2022/02/07 追記

LT参加者の募集に先立って、コアメンバー募集とLT会場の意見募集動画を作りましたので公開します。

mp4動画(1分40秒 17MB)
https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1CMJKYw7MvroPHleuQ3CdS7r971eUmQSW

動画内で発表者と視聴者の双方が参加しやすい配信/会議サービスの要件を記載しています。
こういったサービスをほとんど知らないので、諸賢の忌憚ないご意見ご要望をいただければ幸いです。
以下、動画記載の要件案です。

1. 複数人が発表できる
   何らかの形で別々の発表者がLTできること
2. 100人超が視聴できる
   視聴者はログインせずに視聴できることが望ましい
3. 視聴者がコメントをリアルタイム投稿できる
   発表を見ながらコメントして盛り上がりたい
   コメントはログイン必須でもOK！
   スマホ視聴者は動画サイトとチャットサイトを同時に開きにくいので発表とコメントを一つのサイトで完結できるサービスが良い？
4. 動画形式もスライド+ライブ配信も許容できる
   事前にこのような動画を投稿する形式とスライド等を使ったWeb発表形式を両立できると参加者の自由度が上がるため

もし他にも気軽に参加するための意見や提案があれば回答やチャットをお願いします。

なお募集動画を作成した理由は、私個人が「こういう動画があれば顔出しと声出しNGの方が参加しやすい呼び水になるのではないか」と思い立ったからです。(そしてLTの練習もひそかに意図しています)
スタック・オーバーフローの公式動画ではなく、個人制作の動画ですのであしからずご承知願います。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

このイベント企画は不成立とさせていただき、新たに[正式版1周年記念イベント](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3813/9820)を企画いたします。
大変申し訳ありませんが、イベントの詳細については上記のリンク先をご参照ください。