# モデレーター選挙の立候補者数が４人未満だったため、正式版としての選挙がキャンセルされました：次のステップとは？

Tags: 討議, モデレーション, 選挙

Stack Exchange ネットワークにおける全てのサイトでは、各サイトが順調に運営されるためのモデレーションチームが必要です。現在、このコミュニティはベータ時代に暫定モデレーターとして務めてくれた cubick、nekketsuuu、そして YukiInoue によってバランスよくモデレートされています。[2021年12月](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3653/14055)、スタック・オーバーフローは他の [58の SE サイトとともにベータラベルを削除](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/374096/208518)しました。2022年3月には[「正式版」として初めての選挙](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/election/1)を開催しようとしましたが、残念ながら立候補者数が正式選挙に必要な4名に満たなかったため、選挙はキャンセルされました。

サイトがベータ版である間、[選挙には競争力は必要ありません](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314459/experimenting-with-pro-tempore-elections)。ただし、サイトがベータラベルを失うと選挙は投票段階に進み、正式版として成功したと見なされるため競争力が必要となります。モデレーターポジションの枠よりも少なくとも1人多くの立候補者がいる場合、選挙は競争力があるものと定義されます。卒業選挙では、暫定版モデレーターは正式版のサイトモデレーターとして継続できるよう正式に立候補する必要があり、卒業選挙でのモデレーターポジション枠は3であるため少なくとも4人の立候補者が必要とされます。

残念ながら今回立候補くださったのは現在のモデレーター3人のうち2人だけでしたが、合計4人の立候補者が必要です。[2015年1月にこのポリシーが作成](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257614/graduation-site-closure-and-a-clearer-outlook-on-the-health-of-se-sites)されて以降、積極的にモデレーターとしてステップアップするサイトユーザーの存在こそが各サイトを存続させるための大切な出発点であると言えます。それなしではサイト閉鎖というリスクが伴いますが、すぐに閉鎖されるというわけではないのでこの時点で心配しなくてもよいでしょう。今日、私はこのサイトの次の選挙について話し合うために、コミュニティ管理チームに代わって投稿しています。今後の選挙を成功させるためには、ステップアップしモデレーターとして役割を果たせる資格のあるコミュニティメンバーが必要なのです。

### 次のステップ

次の選挙を設定する前に、まずは2022年9月まで保留すると良いのではないかと思いました。その間に、モデレーションチームに参加したいと自主的に思う、選挙で立候補するユーザー仲間を探せるのではないでしょうか。この次の選挙はそのような前向きなユーザーを迎え入れることができるでしょう。このサイトのモデレーターとして立候補したいという4人が9月までに見つからない場合、次のステップを再度検討する必要が出てくるでしょう。モデレーションチームは、現在3人のモデレーターが配属されていますが、サイトは依然として独立した立場にあり、全員に継続する意思がある限り、選挙をスキップすることも可能なのではないでしょうか。ただし、モデレーターの誰かが辞任を希望する場合には、上記のように、このコミュニティをクリーンでスパムのない状態に保つためにも代わりの手段を見つけなくてはなりません。

選挙プロセスについて質問がありますか？またはモデレーターとして立候補できないような懸念事項がありますか？どうぞお知らせください。私たちはできる限り対処するよう最善を尽くします。